# How to download a file from GitHub Container Registry (CLI command, GitHub Packages)

Tags: github, curl, command-line, containers, github-package-registry

How can I download a package from GitHub Packages using the command-line?

I need to download a file from GitHub Packages so that it can be transferred to a machine without an Internet connection for an offline install. But it's not clear how I can download the file.

For example, let's consider the [`wget` package](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pkgs/container/core%2Fwget) in the [Homebrew organization](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/packages) on GitHub Packages.

- https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pkgs/container/core%2Fwget

I was successfully able to download the manifest with the following command

```
curl -o manifest.json -v -H "Authorization: Bearer QQ==" -H 'Accept: application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json' https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/wget/manifests/1.24.5
```

And here is an example execution of the above commands:

```
user@disp897:~$ curl -o manifest.json -v -H "Authorization: Bearer QQ==" -H 'Accept: application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json' https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/wget/manifests/1.24.5
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 140.82.121.33:443...
* Connected to ghcr.io (140.82.121.33) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [122 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [19 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [3256 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
{ [520 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [36 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [36 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=*.ghcr.io
*  start date: Jul 10 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Jul  9 23:59:59 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "ghcr.io" matched cert's "ghcr.io"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert Global G2 TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
} [5 bytes data]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x5f5c1971a810)
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /v2/homebrew/core/wget/manifests/1.24.5 HTTP/2
> Host: ghcr.io
> user-agent: curl/7.74.0
> authorization: Bearer QQ==
> accept: application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json
> 
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [57 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [57 bytes data]
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
{ [5 bytes data]
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
} [5 bytes data]
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0< HTTP/2 200 
< content-length: 12448
< content-type: application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json
< docker-content-digest: sha256:f7dd153445ffd9ec96cc95d8829cd4afca6ca04b20acbd52cbbd13cfe9aeda5b
< docker-distribution-api-version: registry/2.0
< etag: "sha256:f7dd153445ffd9ec96cc95d8829cd4afca6ca04b20acbd52cbbd13cfe9aeda5b"
< date: Fri, 15 Mar 2024 05:16:30 GMT
< x-github-request-id: B984:0DCC:46A7360:4866BBC:65F3D9AD
< 
{ [1000 bytes data]
100 12448  100 12448    0     0   8491      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  8485
* Connection #0 to host ghcr.io left intact
user@disp897:~$ 

user@disp897:~$ head manifest.json 
{
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "manifests": [
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json",
      "digest": "sha256:c5ae04188725dc26a627b5a6309b2c722cff1d1e01ca2dc822bfa0ef5d4bb2e7",
      "size": 2542,
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "arm64",
        "os": "darwin",
user@disp897:~$
```

What I can't figure out, however, is how to parse the manifest file and use it to download the actual package from the GitHub Container Registry.

How can I download an actual package from a GitHub Container Registry using `curl`?

Comment: Are you looking for something like an offline homebrew? You could study homebrew itself for that.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I already have the "offline homebrew" problem solved. I've been doing it for years. The problem is that they moved their assets from Bintray to GitHub Packages. While it was trivial to download the files from Bintray, it's extremely non-trivial to figure out how to download the packages from GHCR. This question isn't about Homebrew; that's out of scope. This question is asking how to download an arbitrary package from the GItHub Container Registry using `curl`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, honestly. It kind-of seems as if you wanted a Docker image, which is what GHCR provides. The term "package" in that context is a bit confusing, especially since you brought homebrew into the discussion. If it's a Docker image, you can extract it via CLI into a simple file archive (TAR, I believe). You can transfer it to the other machine and there load it with the CLI.

Comment: Yes, if the package is a tarball, then please answer this question with how to download it.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't even know what package you're talking about!!! If it's a Docker image, why not call it an image to clarify? And for that, as mentioned, you can use the CLI, i.e. `docker save ..` and `docker load ..`.

Comment: If it's possible to use `docker save` then please answer the question with the example package provided in the question: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pkgs/container/core%2Fwget

Comment: No. `docker save` is for Docker images. Click the link you posted above. Click the "OS / Arch" view. Correlate the info there with the manifest you downloaded to get the container URL. That's what you could use `docker save` with. This is very specific to homebrew though, not generally applicable to any kind of package.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I've tried that. If you can figure out how to parse the manifest and translate that into some URL to download the package from GitHub, then please post it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use gh command to download the release.

> ```
> # download all assets from a specific release
> $ gh release download v1.2.3
>
> # download only Debian packages for the latest release
> $ gh release download --pattern '*.deb'
>
> # specify multiple file patterns
> $ gh release download -p '*.deb' -p '*.rpm'
>
> # download the archive of the source code for a release
> $ gh release download v1.2.3 --archive=zip
> ```

Reference: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_download

Comment: How do I do this with `curl`, as specified in the question?

Comment: This question is about downloading from GitHub Packages, not a GitHub Release...

Comment: I think the confusion here comes from the use of the term "package", which is indeed what you can retrieve with `gh release ..`.